# What is the largest real number that can be made from using 7 characters?

Tags: computational-mathematics

All operations (multiplication, exponentiation, factorials, etc...) can be used including such functions as the busy beaver.

Comment: Honestly, I think this question is too broad. If you're going to ask a similar question, give a definition of characters and operations.

Comment: What are "all operations"? Give a complete list of operators and functions that can be used.

Comment: Also separtely, why seven? What have you tried? This question is missing all context.

Comment: Do you know what knuth’s up arrow is? But in the end what would it really matter because even with the up arrow notation you are just disguising a bunch of operations and characters as one

Comment: A good candidate for the largest number is $$\large \Sigma(\Sigma(9))$$

Answer (score 2):

If the brackets are counted as characters, then I think that this number should be the largest $9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9}}}}}!$

Comment: Not if the busy beaver function is allowed. Nevertheless +1